# Elementary fact about holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

I found some assertion in this [article](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/JEDP/JEDP_1995___/JEDP_1995____A22_0/JEDP_1995____A22_0.pdf) (bottom of third page) of François Trèves which in a way states that taking a bounded simply connected domain $D$, $H$ the open upper half plane, a  holomorphic function $f$ in $D\cap H$, such that, given an integer $m$, any compact $K$, $\mid f(z)\mid<\frac{1}{\mid\Im(z)\mid^{m}}$ for $z\in K\cap D\cap H$. Then it is possible to find a holomorphic function $g$, continuous in $\overline{D\cap H}$ such that

$$f(x+it) = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)^{m+1}g(x+it)$$

Anyone knows how to prove that ? (I am not concerned with the polynomial growth condition, because even for abounded function, $m=0$, I don't know how to do that)

2 remarks :

- This is used to prove the following well-know complex analysis fact : given an integer $m$, any compact $K$, and a holomorphic function on a domain $D = U+i\Gamma$, where $U$ is an open set in the real space, $\Gamma$ a cone not containing $0$, $\mid f(z)\mid<\frac{1}{\mid\Im(z)\mid^{m}}$ for $z\in K\cap D$, the following limit exists

  $$\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_{D}f(x+i\varepsilon\gamma)\phi(x)dx$$

where $\gamma\in\Gamma$

- I precise that in his article, this in stated in a several complex variables context, using holomorphic functions on wedges with real edges

Comment: @user1952009 I agree. Btw, you should consider $D\cap H$, I'll edit my post, let's consider $D$ simply connected

Comment: (in the one complex variable case) if $f$ is holomorphic on $D$ a simply connected open, then it has a primitive on $D$. I don't know the several complex variables case, but I often read it is much more complicated, so it is very possible the restriction $|f(z)| < |Im(z)|^{-m}$ is for that case

Comment: and I meant :  $f(z)=\frac{1/16}{z−4i}$ on $D=\{z \ \mid 1<|z-4i|<2 \}$  doesn't have a primtive

Comment: @user1952009 thank you, I know that but how for example can you infer $$f(x+it) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} g(x+it)$$ (I take $m=0$) from the fact that $f$ has a primitive ?

Comment: if $g$ is holomorphic then what you wrote means $f(z) = -i g'(z)$

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but this doesn't look very easy to me. For example, $D\cap H$ could be something like a rectangle of height $1$ above each gap of a Cantor set. (In fact, I'm mildly suspicious if it can be true at all, though it might well be.)